# Ошибка при выполнении собранного решения на другом PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Собрал я консольное приложение с данным кодом:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // строка подключения к БД
            string connStr = "server=;port=;username=;password=;database=";

            using (var con = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT steamID, type, why FROM toxics";
                con.Open();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter("toxics.data"))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        writer.Write(reader[0].ToString() + "|" + reader[1].ToString() + "@" + reader[2].ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске на устройстве на котором он был собрал всё работает как надо. Я так понимаю в папке с исполняемым файлом нет какой-то библиотеки, но я все их скопировал из папки с проектом. Пока не пойму. Вот что происходит при запуске на другом ПК:
[image: Скрин 1]
[image: Скрин 2]

```
Сигнатура проблемы:
  Имя события проблемы: CLR20r3
  Сигнатура проблемы 01:    blacklist_undater.exe
  Сигнатура проблемы 02:    1.0.0.0
  Сигнатура проблемы 03:    8dc363ce
  Сигнатура проблемы 04:    System
  Сигнатура проблемы 05:    4.8.4110.0
  Сигнатура проблемы 06:    5de6daea
  Сигнатура проблемы 07:    7ad
  Сигнатура проблемы 08:    12
  Сигнатура проблемы 09:    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySql
  Версия ОС:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Код языка:    1049
  Дополнительные сведения 1:    0a9e
  Дополнительные сведения 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Дополнительные сведения 3:    0a9e
  Дополнительные сведения 4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Ознакомьтесь с заявлением о конфиденциальности в Интернете:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0419

Если заявление о конфиденциальности в Интернете недоступно, ознакомьтесь с его локальным вариантом:
  L:\Windows\system32\ru-RU\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: Мне тут на секунду показалось, что вы все логины пароли от вашей бд опубликовали

Comment: Возможно на том пк версия CLR другая https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/clr#clr-versions

Comment: Да данные к БД в коде, но это не критично, там только 2 тестовые строки.

Comment: @Сергей критично. Как вы смотрите на то, если кто-то совершенно случайно зальет в вашу БД табличку на 10 Терабайт? Смените пароль.

Comment: Вы показали все, кроме текста ошибки.

Comment: "̶s̶e̶r̶v̶e̶r̶=̶s̶e̶r̶v̶e̶r̶6̶8̶.̶h̶o̶s̶t̶i̶n̶g̶.̶r̶e̶g̶.̶r̶u̶;̶p̶o̶r̶t̶=̶3̶3̶0̶6̶;̶u̶s̶e̶r̶n̶a̶m̶e̶=̶u̶0̶9̶9̶9̶5̶7̶0̶_̶u̶c̶;̶p̶a̶s̶s̶w̶o̶r̶d̶=̶8̶8̶8̶8̶q̶w̶e̶r̶@̶;̶d̶a̶t̶a̶b̶a̶s̶e̶=̶u̶0̶9̶9̶9̶5̶7̶0̶_̶b̶l̶a̶c̶k̶l̶i̶s̶t̶"̶
Если что, stackoverflow сохраняет историю изменений

Comment: понял. сейчас сменю.

Comment: А пробовали каким-то клиентом БД с того компьютера к базе приконнектиться?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте для обработки ошибки обернуть ваш код в `try {} catch {}`.

```csharp
try
{
    // using... ваш код
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Сonsole.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Сonsole.WriteLine(ex.TargetSite);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

От этого программа конечно не начнет работать, но перестанет падать и вмеcто этого будет выводить в консоль сообщение об ошибке, и возможно это сообщение даст вам необходимую информацию о том, что же на самом деле произошло.